# How to bind a cell in a gridcontrol to a property in view mode

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="m_grid" SelectionMode="Row" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDT,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="col_A" AllowEditing="False" FieldName="A" />
        <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="col_B" AllowEditing="False" FieldName="B" />
        <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="col_C" AllowEditing="False" FieldName="C" />
        <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="col_D" AllowEditing="False" FieldName="D" />
        <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="col_E" AllowEditing="True" FieldName="E" />
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

I have a `Grid` control in a wpf application am developing using MVVM design battern. My `GridControl` is bound to a `DataTable` in my view model "MyDT". Now one of the columns in "MyDT" is of type bool, so the `GridControl` converts it to a checkbox. This is the only column in my `GridControl` which is editable, the remaining columns are uneditable, I have made sure in the xaml. What I need to do is trigger an event when a checkbox is ticked/unticked in any of the rows in the `GridControl`, by binding to a property in my viewmodel. How would the xaml change?

Comment: are you trying to have a checkbox column column to select data rows?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. Initially all checkboxes are unticked in the grid control since the datatable it is bound to in view model class has initialized that particular column value to false. Now when a user clicks on the checkbox I need to trigger an event which involves doing some other processing like calling a function in a separate user control etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an `ICommand` named `CheckBoxCommand` in your `ViewModel`

```
<dxg:GridColumn>
    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <dxe:CheckEdit 
                Command="{Binding Path=View.DataContext.CheckBoxCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding RowData.Row}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

note that the command parameter is actually your Model so in your ViewModel you can have a command like:

```
private ICommand _checkBoxCommand;
public ICommand CheckBoxCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _checkBoxCommand = _checkBoxCommand ?? new RelayCommand((param) =>
            {
                var model = param as Model;

                // Do whatever with the model.

            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A property is already bound to your checkbox, that is the property in your dt

If you want to deliberately handle check event.. add a checkBoxColumn or templated column instead of Grid Column..

that ways you will have access to checked event or associated command.

Comment: You mean to say that, in the current scenario when I check on the checkbox the property associated with the ItemsSource of gridcontrol which is "MYDT" should get fired in the view model ?

Comment: Because I do see the values changed in the datatable, however control does not explicitly flow to the set property of my datatable.

Comment: you can listen to value changed i guess